# matplotlib.FuncAnimation not removing some data from plot

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib-basemap

I am plotting position data over time with `matplotlib.Basemap` and `matplotlib.Animation`. There is a maximum of `point_number` points, with points being gradually introduced and then removed by being present or not in the data.

i.e.

```
day 1
--------
1 some-lon some-lat
2 some-lon some-lat

day 2
--------
1 some-lon some-lat
2 some-lon some-lat
3 some-lon some-lat

day 3
--------
2 some-lon some-lat
```

Everything animates fine until the number of points begins to decrease (as on day 3), at which point a number of points plotted  (equal to those no longer present on day 3) remain frozen on the map.

This appears to be due to the `init()` routine not doing its job. As I am setting each point equal to an empty object, I can't seem to figure out why it is doing this.

**init() function**:

```
def init():
for pt in pts_dots:
    pt.set_data([], [])

    return pts_dots
```

**animation() function**:

```
def animate(i):
    # filter out daily data from pandas dataframe
    lons = data.lons[data.daynr==dates[i]].values
    lats = data.lats[data.daynr==dates[i]].values

    for z in range(len(lons)):
        x, y = m(lons[z],lats[z])
        pts_dots[z].set_data(x, y)

    # attempting to "empty" objects where values are absent
    for z in range(point_number-len(lons)):
        pts_dots[z].set_data([],[])

    return pts_dots
```

**animation call**:

```
    pts_dots = [[] for i in range(point_number)] # Animation point global list

    for i in range(point_number):
        pts_dots[i] = m.plot(x,y, 'ro', markersize=5)[0]

    anim = animation.FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), animate,
                                   init_func=init, frames=f_num,
                                   interval=animate_range, blit=True)
```

Any idea what may be going on here? Thanks!

**Data snippet**:

```
+------+-------+----------+-------------+-------------+
|      | daynr | point_id |     lons    |     lats    |
+------+-------+----------+-------------+-------------+
| 171  |  7.0  |    2     | -4.45366398 | 60.72650532 |
| 241  |  8.0  |    2     | -4.00647587 | 61.01281524 |
| 242  |  8.0  |    3     | -4.45183701 | 60.71743553 |
| 243  |  8.0  |    5     | -7.92443966 | 61.34647079 |
| 325  |  9.0  |    2     |   -3.55301  | 61.30035716 |
| 326  |  9.0  |    3     | -3.99834681 | 61.00068353 |
| 327  |  9.0  |    4     | -4.44165093 | 60.72803087 |
| 328  |  9.0  |    5     | -7.41926307 | 61.61805212 |
| 412  |  10.0 |    1     | -7.90065375 | 61.34230534 |
| 413  |  10.0 |    2     | -3.09927833 |  61.5869605 |
| 414  |  10.0 |    3     | -3.54755914 | 61.28483512 |
| 415  |  10.0 |    4     | -3.99194122 | 61.01493663 |
| 416  |  10.0 |    5     | -5.82052964 | 62.12547394 |
| 504  |  11.0 |    1     | -7.40200065 | 61.61242493 |
| 505  |  11.0 |    2     | -2.63697802 | 61.87711064 |
| 506  |  11.0 |    3     | -3.08461278 | 61.57107991 |
| 507  |  11.0 |    4     | -3.53868532 |  61.2991389 |
| 508  |  11.0 |    5     | -5.30487041 |  62.3976168 |
| 597  |  12.0 |    1     | -6.60641348 | 62.26026119 |
| 598  |  12.0 |    2     | -2.17446179 | 62.16981877 |
| 599  |  12.0 |    3     | -2.62998793 | 61.86510687 |
| 600  |  12.0 |    4     | -3.08032268 | 61.58919812 |
| 601  |  12.0 |    5     | -4.79651341 | 62.67039254 |
| 694  |  13.0 |    1     | -6.08703929 | 62.53172291 |
| 695  |  13.0 |    2     |  -1.7127866 | 62.46318164 |
| 696  |  13.0 |    3     | -2.17614685 | 62.15537983 |
| 697  |  13.0 |    4     | -2.62316597 | 61.88067335 |
| 698  |  13.0 |    5     | -4.28827737 | 62.94939414 |
| 794  |  14.0 |    1     | -5.56028452 | 62.79949887 |
| 795  |  14.0 |    2     | -1.24521666 | 62.75546024 |
| 796  |  14.0 |    3     | -1.71300992 | 62.44833943 |
| 797  |  14.0 |    4     | -2.16482898 | 62.17056137 |
| 798  |  14.0 |    5     | -3.77037748 |  63.2290821 |
| 894  |  15.0 |    1     | -5.71432399 | 62.44689183 |
| 895  |  15.0 |    2     | -0.77802644 |  63.0510241 |
| 896  |  15.0 |    3     | -1.25380314 | 62.74107774 |
| 897  |  15.0 |    4     |  -1.7003722 | 62.46102404 |
| 898  |  15.0 |    5     | -3.25720983 |  63.5068827 |
| 994  |  16.0 |    1     | -5.59137769 | 62.08532967 |
| 995  |  16.0 |    2     | -0.30805077 | 63.34665516 |
| 996  |  16.0 |    3     | -0.78319223 | 63.03575662 |
| 997  |  16.0 |    4     | -1.23957285 | 62.75271172 |
| 998  |  16.0 |    5     | -2.75050842 | 63.78709738 |
| 1094 |  17.0 |    1     | -5.71709194 | 61.72990759 |
| 1095 |  17.0 |    2     |  0.15062701 | 63.64276531 |
| 1096 |  17.0 |    3     | -1.42640622 |  62.8293313 |
| 1097 |  17.0 |    4     | -0.77191719 | 63.04631626 |
| 1098 |  17.0 |    5     | -2.23675898 | 64.07140725 |
| 1194 |  18.0 |    1     | -5.84315356 | 61.37380764 |
| 1195 |  18.0 |    2     | -0.37369111 | 63.37029853 |
| 1196 |  18.0 |    3     | -1.90305652 | 62.54377504 |
| 1197 |  18.0 |    4     | -0.30628721 | 63.33942171 |
| 1198 |  18.0 |    5     |  -1.7196634 |  64.355484  |
| 1294 |  19.0 |    1     |  -5.2628807 |  61.1454648 |
| 1295 |  19.0 |    2     | -0.92225023 | 63.11307572 |
| 1296 |  19.0 |    3     | -2.32185799 | 62.24064625 |
| 1297 |  19.0 |    4     |  0.16220025 | 63.63782642 |
| 1298 |  19.0 |    5     | -2.27735206 | 64.08689711 |
| 1394 |  20.0 |    1     | -6.00380815 | 61.17190429 |
| 1395 |  20.0 |    2     | -1.57348486 | 62.90934753 |
| 1396 |  20.0 |    3     |  -2.9061956 | 62.00581576 |
| 1397 |  20.0 |    4     |  0.63065135 |  63.9345848 |
| 1398 |  20.0 |    5     | -2.49747739 |  63.7426637 |
| 1493 |  21.0 |    1     | -6.75167242 | 61.22029862 |
| 1494 |  21.0 |    2     | -1.97949208 | 62.59848653 |
| 1495 |  21.0 |    3     | -3.56641468 | 61.82230198 |
| 1496 |  21.0 |    4     |  0.0176544  | 63.69946287 |
| 1497 |  21.0 |    5     | -2.85047365 | 63.41953451 |
| 1587 |  22.0 |    1     | -7.49038571 |  61.2681404 |
| 1588 |  22.0 |    2     | -2.56974239 | 62.35995893 |
| 1589 |  22.0 |    3     | -4.03747684 | 61.54029225 |
| 1590 |  22.0 |    4     | -0.56825407 | 63.45703496 |
| 1591 |  22.0 |    5     | -3.10192883 |  63.0782619 |
| 1679 |  23.0 |    1     | -6.78479647 | 61.14594969 |
| 1680 |  23.0 |    2     | -3.15971365 | 62.12655957 |
| 1681 |  23.0 |    3     | -4.77551934 | 61.48315198 |
| 1682 |  23.0 |    4     | -1.20257268 | 63.23739608 |
| 1683 |  23.0 |    5     | -3.35273464 | 62.73608292 |
| 1766 |  24.0 |    1     | -7.48894785 | 61.26483922 |
| 1767 |  24.0 |    2     | -3.61670316 | 61.83964718 |
| 1768 |  24.0 |    3     | -5.44135019 | 61.31067048 |
| 1769 |  24.0 |    4     | -1.68497622 | 62.95139694 |
| 1770 |  24.0 |    5     | -3.60826477 | 62.39478414 |
| 1851 |  25.0 |    2     |  -4.1577626 | 61.58987649 |
| 1852 |  25.0 |    3     | -6.09732902 | 61.13961171 |
| 1853 |  25.0 |    4     | -2.36817354 | 62.77207285 |
| 1854 |  25.0 |    5     | -4.09030225 | 62.10817621 |
| 1934 |  26.0 |    1     | -6.78250548 | 61.14562163 |
| 1935 |  26.0 |    2     | -4.26932018 | 61.23393004 |
| 1936 |  26.0 |    3     | -5.46586982 | 60.95023225 |
| 1937 |  26.0 |    4     |  -2.903176  | 62.50884564 |
| 1938 |  26.0 |    5     | -4.57302758 | 61.82364897 |
| 2018 |  27.0 |    1     | -7.15642824 |  61.2098756 |
| 2019 |  27.0 |    2     | -4.38717574 | 60.87630252 |
| 2020 |  27.0 |    3     | -4.77991484 | 60.80961114 |
| 2021 |  27.0 |    4     |  -3.4821231 | 62.26664477 |
| 2022 |  27.0 |    5     | -4.51805801 | 61.46261821 |
| 2101 |  28.0 |    1     | -6.45087653 | 61.08953278 |
| 2102 |  28.0 |    2     | -5.10962837 | 60.95808701 |
| 2103 |  28.0 |    3     | -5.47168995 | 60.92719014 |
| 2104 |  28.0 |    4     | -3.85846896 | 61.95312546 |
| 2105 |  28.0 |    5     | -4.31627368 | 61.11404727 |
| 2181 |  29.0 |    1     | -7.15367019 | 61.20996396 |
| 2182 |  29.0 |    2     |  -4.4685451 | 60.77766143 |
| 2183 |  29.0 |    3     | -5.57426471 | 60.93922674 |
| 2184 |  29.0 |    4     |  -4.3348975 | 61.66888486 |
| 2185 |  29.0 |    5     | -4.96446093 | 60.93709383 |
| 2254 |  30.0 |    2     | -4.42456883 | 60.73181243 |
| 2255 |  30.0 |    4     | -4.22187879 | 61.30985271 |
| 2256 |  30.0 |    5     |  -5.6922579 | 60.98634563 |
| 2322 |  31.0 |    4     | -4.96950637 |  61.314032  |
| 2323 |  31.0 |    5     | -6.39554038 | 61.09783538 |
| 2390 |  32.0 |    3     | -6.24088918 |  61.0563245 |
| 2391 |  32.0 |    4     | -4.55267037 | 61.01582872 |
| 2392 |  32.0 |    5     | -6.35170419 | 61.07596667 |
| 2454 |  33.0 |    4     | -5.27982039 | 60.95963728 |
| 2455 |  33.0 |    5     | -7.05496009 | 61.19298776 |
| 2514 |  34.0 |    1     | -6.39671804 | 61.08225977 |
| 2515 |  34.0 |    4     | -6.00036916 | 61.04043063 |
| 2516 |  34.0 |    5     | -6.34544218 | 61.07435974 |
| 2571 |  35.0 |    4     |  -6.3522571 | 61.07221175 |
| 2572 |  35.0 |    5     | -6.35287665 | 61.07582546 |
| 2659 |  37.0 |    5     | -5.96382779 | 61.00587669 |
| 2758 |  42.0 |    2     | -5.09121351 | 60.85182831 |
| 2891 |  58.0 |    4     | -5.65987894 | 60.95238083 |
| 2895 |  59.0 |    4     | -5.96656035 |  61.0058948 |
| 2898 |  64.0 |    4     | -6.67680629 | 61.12872095 |
+------+-------+----------+-------------+-------------+
```

Comment: Can you include a snippet of your test data?

Comment: So is `daynr` the day? ie; day 1, etc. Also, is `dates` a separate `dict`..?

Comment: `daynr` is the day, and `dates` is a list of unique dates that I pulled from the dataframe using `np.unique()`.